# How to implement Docusign in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

How to implement Docusign in asp.net core. I tried to install nuget package but its not working for .net core. Any idea for how can I implement it in .net core 1.1

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).